# leniuNot able to enter value in text box of form in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi I am using way2sms website and in send sms screen i am not able to enter the mobile number in mobile number field using selenium webdriver.
HTML Code: `

```
form id="smsFrm" name="smsFrm" method="post">
<input id="ssaction" type="hidden" name="ssaction" value="ss"/>
<input id="Token" type="hidden" name="Token" value="F448FDFD10E9288F9B4A204EF40EB29A.w803"/>
<div id="smilebox" style=" display:none;">
<div class="Sms fl">
<label>Mobile Number</label>
<div class="m91">
<span>+91</span>
<input id="mobile" type="text" onchange="javascript:dispLocMob(this);" onkeydown="javascript:dispLocMob(this);" onkeyup="javascript:dispLocMob(this);" value="" maxlength="10" placeholder="Mobile Number" name="mobile"/>
</div>`
```

Selenium Code :

```
`obj.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sendSMS']/a")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
//obj.findElement(By.id("mobile")).sendKeys("8186867724");
obj.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mobile']")).sendKeys("1234567890");`
```

Comment: Where is your code? and the html?

Comment: you can check the html code in way2sms.com of mobile number entering in send sms screen and code is 
obj.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sendSM/a")).click();  //element.findElement(By.id("mobile")).sendKeys("8186867724");
//obj.findElement(By.xpath("//div//div//form[@id='smsFrm']//div//div//input[@placeholder='Mobile Number']")).click();
obj.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='mobile']")).sendKeys("1234567890");

Comment: *you can check the html code in way2sms.com*. This is **not** how it works. If you want help from people here you need to put in your question (and not in the comments) the relevant code and html.

Comment: thanks for telling. I updated HTML and selenium code

Comment: so, what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your element has an id, which is always the best way to address an HTML element using Selenium - very simple but still absolutely unique (bc otherwise it wouldn't be valid HTML). So try:

```
findElement(By.id("username"))
```

Full C# sample (should be similar in Java):

```
static void Main()
{
    var driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://site23.way2sms.com/content/index.html");
    IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("username"));
    element.SendKeys("000");
}
```

Comment: Oops! I wrote "#username" instead of "username", which is the CSS notation. Sorry! I corrected this in the answer.

Comment: It does. I'm using ChromeDriver 2.21.371459 on Windows 7. I added some sample code for you.

Comment: i tried with these code but not working obj.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
obj.findElement(By.id("mobile")).sendKeys("8186867724");

Comment: Why are you searching for id "mobile"? The id of the mobile number field is "username".

Comment: I think you got my question wrong. I am asking for entering mobile number in send sms screen not for login

Comment: Can you post the exact URL please?

Comment: http://site23.way2sms.com/main.action?section=s&Token=2B01C59A3FB6EBA0A5FB46BD31CEC9A1.w809&vfType=register_verify

Comment: Any update on this question. I am not able to detect now also

Answer (score 0):

I switched to the frame and got it detected.
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("frame")));
driver.findElement(By.id("mobile")).sendKeys("123456");